# How TLS Protocol propagation in case of multi-tier system

Tags: ssl, request, response

We came across a scenario where need to upgrade our servers in partial chunks to support TLS1.2 protocol.

We are not expected to run any network capture tool on our production servers like wireshark , etc because it is harmful, so could you please help me in understanding how exactly our protocol handshakes work in case of multi-tier system.

Suppose, our request response is as follows:

```
A(Client) <--> B(Web Server) <--> C (SOA Servers) <--> D (Third Party Server)
```

Let me elaborate each entity:

- A (Client) : can have OS from Windows7 to windows 10
- B (Web Server) : Windows Server 2012R2
- C (SOA Servers) : Windows Server 2012R2 + "SchUseStrongCrypto" is enabled
- D (Third Party Server) : Can have OS from Windows Server 2008R2 to Window Server 2012R

I am interested to know is there any dependency of protocol in-between multi-tier communication channel?

How actually will the protocol propagate in the above scenario?

Suppose if TLS1.1 is used in-between A to B then is it possible to use TLS1.2 in-between B to C OR C to D?

Comment: If each `<-->` is an HTTPS call, then each one has its own independent TLS handshake and hence choice of protocols and versions, there is no correlations. Of course, the security of the whole system is the one of the weakest link, so if all speak TLS 1.2 but one speaks SSLv3.0 (chosen for dramatic effect), then this is your level of security, in generic terms.

Comment: It means, it is possible we may have A to B communication over TLS1.1 protocol but B to C, tls1.2 because both support TLS1.2 in some cases and it is not going to break request and response encryption and decryption mechanism and client will receive expected result no matter whether request changes TLS protocol version while communicating over muti-tier system.